# When can I say "WLOG that $E(X)=E(Y)=0$" in the proof of probability inequalities

Tags: probability

In Grimmett's 《Probability and Random Processes》, there is an exercise in Section 4.6 :

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with correlation $\rho$. Show that $E(var(Y|X))\leq(1-\rho^2)var(Y)$

And in the solution manual, it is claimed in the first line that "We may assume without loss of generality that $EX=EY=0$", and I can't figure out under what circumstances can I apply the technique.

Best regards!

Comment: In papers, I say w.l.o.g., when it's absolutely clear to anyone remotely familiar with the field why it's indeed "w.l.o.g." (in most cases, it's some kind of symmetry). If the book mentioned before that conditional variance doesn't depend on the expectations (i.e. you can consider $Y-c$ for any constant $c$ instead of $Y$, and, in particular, $c = E[Y]$), then I would say that it's OK to use it here.

Comment: Pearson correlation and variance are both translation-invariant. For that matter, Pearson correlation is scale-invariant too.

Comment: @Dmitry I can understand the case for $Y$. But when it comes to $X$, which is in the condition, I can't understand why subtracting a constant doesn't change anything.

Comment: You're just subtracting the mean value from $X$ and $Y$. We don't care what the mean value of the distributions is because we are thinking about their correlation with each other.

Comment: @KTang, I agree that it's not trivial, since for $X'=X - E[X]$, $Var(Y | X')$ is not the same as $Var(Y | X)$. If it was not explained in the book why you can use shift $X$ in this case, I wouldn't use w.l.o.g.

Comment: @KTang Is anything said about the domain of the variance of $Y$? If I finish my calculation I obtain $\sigma_y^2\cdot \left( 1-\rho^2\right)$.

Comment: @callculus42 Actually,the question is just put forward as I have stated above, with no information about the domain of $var(Y)$. I'm curious about the calculation you have done, can you share more details with me, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Nego Sure. But can you point out where you need more details, i.e. the calculation I've done so far or the calculation which has to be done?

Comment: @nego. Anytime, in statistics, where something is being proven and it involves only variances and covariances ( and not means ), then one can always assume wlog that the means are zero because the var and the cov formulae involve subtraction of the mean in them so assuming that the mean equals zero cannot effect the result.  A good example is chebyshev's inequality. That inequality involves the mean so one CANNOT assume wlog that the mean is zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality

Answer (score 2):

Define variables $Y’ = Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]$ and similarly for $X’$. Then $X’$ and $Y’$ have correlation $\rho$, and $\mathbb{E}[var(X’ \mid Y’)] = \mathbb{E}[var(X \mid Y)]$. Furthermore, $\mathbb{E}[X’] = \mathbb{E}[Y’] = 0$. This is why we can assume WLOG that the expected values of $X$ and $Y$ are zero - we can reduce to this case using $X’$ and $Y’$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a intuitive explanation why we the expected values do not affect $E\left( Var(Y|X)\right)$. So I show the term when the random variables $X,Y$ do have an expected value and are normal distributed with the correlation coefficient $\rho$. From the law of total variance we know that

$${Var}(Y) = E[{Var}(Y |X)] + Var(E[Y |X])\Rightarrow E[{Var}(Y |X)]={Var}(Y)-Var(E[Y |X])  $$

And you probably know that

$$E[Y |X]=\mu_y+\rho \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}(X-\mu_x)$$

If we now calculate the variance of it, the expected values disappear. Thus $E\left( Var(Y|X)\right)$ has no expected value at all. I agree to the comments that the w.l.o.g assumption should have been explained. Maybe it is explained in the corresponding chapter of the book.

Comment: $X-\mu_x$ is the same thing as $X-E(X)$ which is the same thing as $X'=X-E(X)$ where $X'$ has $E(X')=0$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Yes. But I had problems to transfer it to  the conditional variance. So I did it this way.

Comment: Isn't that an intuitive explanation then? Anyway have a vote.

Comment: @SuzuHirose  Not for me. me. Probably Ì'm the only one.:-) Thanks for the vote.

Comment: This is really an intuitive answer! Thanks a lot! I think now the w.l.o.g makes more sense to me. btw I have gone through the corresponding chapter again and I think I haven't met any explanation to this……

Comment: @Nego In context of  universitary lectures sometimes information are somehow hidden and hard to find. But probably it is really  mentioned nowhere. Since I couldn't read the chapter (no preview) I couldn't check if there is any helpful content in the previous chapter(s).